# Redirect site URLs from old year to new year

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a WordPress site with tons of posts with permalinks containing the previous year '2015'. I want to redirect all the URLs containing that year to the new year '2016' with htaccess.

Example:

From:

http://www.my-domain.com/archive/slug-of-post-2015

To:

http://www.my-domain.com/archive/slug-of-post-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as very first rule (just below `RewriteEngine On` line) in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(archive/.+)-2015(.*)$ /$1-2016$2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. Need an edit. 2015 isn't necessarily in the end of the link. I want to set a path before 2015, as in the question, it's 'archive' directory.